# SQL Server count from two tables join with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm working with SQL Server 2008. I have two tables `Tab1` and `Tab2` and I want to calculate the number of rows in `Tab1` with condition (not null) of column from `Tab2`.

I tried this query:

```
Select count(H.ID) 
From Tab1 H 
Join Tab2 A On A.Compte = H.charging_Id 
Where A.FLAG IS NULL
```

But this query doesn't return the correct value.

Comment: Maybe try a `LEFT JOIN` or change the `IS NULL` to `IS NOT NULL`? Expected results and schema would be wildly helpful...

Comment: you are calculating count(a  column) where some column is null,what does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a lack of understanding of the effect joins have on data. Tab2 likely in a one to many relationship with table 1. So when you join to it, you increase the number of records returned.  If I understand you correctly, you want a count of all the records in tab1 which do not have a related record in tabl2. In this case where not exists is what you want to use.

```
Select count(H.ID) 
from   Tab1 H 
where not exists (select   * from Tab2 
    where Compte = H.charging_Id )
```

Comment: I want to count the number of rows  in Tab1 which the the value of **chargingID** is the same as the **compte** from the Tab2 with condition : a column from tab2 (**Flag**) must be not Null

Comment: Not entirely understanding what you want. Please post some sample data showing what resultsyou expect and what the current data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(H.ID) 
From Tab1 H 
Join Tab2 A On A.Compte = H.charging_Id And A.FLAG IS NOT NULL
```

If I understood you correctly, with this your inner join will not include null values of the second table.

Comment: Which Join should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

Well from your question and comment (Require count of table 1; table1's compte id is equqal to table2's chargingid), you just need to modify the 'NULL' to 'NOT NULL', just in case if you have null values in table1 or 2, have included a isnull condition as well:

```
Select count(H.ID) 
From Tab1 H 
Join Tab2 A On ISNULL(A.Compte,0) = ISNULL(H.charging_Id,0)
Where A.FLAG IS NOT NULL
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

use inner join like :

```
Select count(H.ID) 
From Tab1 H 
INNER Join Tab2 A On A.Compte = H.charging_Id 
Where A.FLAG IS NULL
```